# labelformatter android graphview

Tags: android, date, time

I want to represent date and time on the x axis in the format: dd:mm:yy @ hh:mm:ss

right now, I have unix timestamp as the  x values.

how to convert it and show date and time on the x values?

I am using android graphview library.

please explain using label formatter.

Comment: Prefer using MPAndroidChart library.

Comment: cant, this is the last leg !

Comment: can you explain the syntax of customlabel?

Comment: cant figure it out